# PHP password_hash and password_verify incorrect false positive?

Tags: php, hash, passwords, password-protection, verify

im new to PHP password functions, but this seems incorrect to me.

```
<?php
$peppa = "ahsd88ah31qnaksdn9325h9asdgh3no1i3859173o5bnn789a79on352390sfm!89235n@n90a&*^T#&*$#$!*$#)";
$pw = 'jesustake-thewheel';
$peppered = $pw . $peppa;

$passhash = password_hash($peppered, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
var_dump($passhash);

echo "<br>";

$should_fail = $pw . $peppa . ".1asd223";
echo password_verify($should_fail, $passhash);

?>
```

As you can see im adding some additional random characters to the end of my should_fail test against password, but its still returning True for a match

I would exepct this to fail as there are additional characters at the end that shouldnt match the original... am i missing something obvious here or is this a bug in php (possibly my php)

Version 15.6.30

Comment: It's not a bug.... PHP only takes the first 72 characters of the password string for the hash and verify; and this is a [limit of the bcrypt hashing algorithm](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39849/does-bcrypt-have-a-maximum-password-length)

Comment: Ahhh okay i missed that in the docs thnak you - so if i wanted to use any sort of add on type security trailing 'pepper' i have to limit the password to ~60 and then have a max 12chr pepper - unless, does the random salt count towards that limit to? Or not included?

Comment: In practice there isn't much need for a pepper anyway; if its value is discovered once, it doesn't make life any harder for an attacker. The real security comes from the unique salt per hash which `password_hash` automatically adds. It adds orders of magnitude more complexity to attacking the hash than a pepper does.

Comment: That 72-byte limit is the entire length of the peppered/password string passed through to bcrypt by the password functions. Other algorithms may have different limits, but for the moment the password functions only support bcrypt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MarkBaker already mentioned in his comment, this is a limitation of the BCrypt algorithm, which truncates passwords to 72 characters. For passwords this is more than enough and not a security problem, but in your case it seems you reach this limit because you want to add a pepper.

Never should a password be truncated because of adding a pepper. A pepper can [increase security of weak passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/23520/8343). Assuming that the pepper is of reasonable size, passwords which reach the limitation are very strong, and for those passwords a pepper is not necessary. So if you put the pepper at the end, you loose a part of the pepper, which is better than loosing a part of the password.

That said, there are much better ways to add a pepper. You get the same benefits from encrypting (twoway) the hash with a server side key. This key is actually similar to the pepper, but you have the advantage that you can exchange the key whenever this seems necessary (a pepper becomes part of the password and cannot be changed until the next login). I tried to explain this at the end of my tutorial about [safely storing passwords](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php). If encryption is not an option for you, then at least use a HMAC to combine the pepper with the password.

Comment: Thanks - i see your example on http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#bcrypt - quick question. In this case the serversidekey isnt something specially generated with SSL or anything right? Just random characters of any type?

Comment: Hey - so I used your encryption method from the link I posted above in conjunction with password_hash and verify - but even though my password_hash before and after the encrypt/decrypt visually look the same when I print them, verify returns False... any idea why?

Comment: @aescript - Yes it has nothing to do with private/public keys, the key is just a sequence of random characters (symmetric encryption). Most encryption algorithms have their own requirements about the lenght of the key though.

Comment: Disregard my last question - was working late with no sleep and i was using password verify with the hash value versus the has value... not the str password vs the hash. MY BAD. sleepy mistakes. thanks all for the help!

Comment: One more question - the return type of your encryption example... i can store it as a varchar if i do a bin2hex on it, but I am not able to enter it into a binary field in mysql - what field type should I be using for that?

Comment: @aescript - The return type is just a binary string. I myself think that the easiest and most robust way is to store it base64 encoded, this way you never have problems with SQL and other escaping. Base64 generates shorter strings than bintohex, so I would prefer `base64_encode()`. The documentation of password_hash() recommends to use `varchar(255)`, to be future proof, this is surely a good idea.